# Encrypt the XML element whie writing to the file in java

Tags: java, xml, security

I have java application that sending(`HTTP post method`) credit card numbers to the supplier via the XML. 
When writing the XML file, currently credit card number also printing in the file. But it is not good practice to write the credit card numbers directly in to the file without encrypting.

I do not want to encrypt the entire XML, because we are sending the secure information through `HTTPS` link and hence I assume it provide necessary security.  So I want to encrypt only the credit card number element while writing to the file in the Java environment.

```
String xmlRequest = <?xml version='1.0'?> 
  <ReservationRequest>
    <Passenger>
    <firstName>XXX</firstName>
    <lastName>YYY</lastName>
    </Passenger>    
    <CreditCard Currency='USD'>
      <Number>1234567812345678</Number>
      <cvv>123</cvv>
      <Expiration>12/12</Expiration>
    </CreditCard>
  </ReservationRequest>
```

Please note that I want to write to file the same string that send to the supplier.

Comment: When you say "Write to file" do you just mean your logs?

Comment: yes, exactly write. we have log folder and it contain all the XML logs

Comment: In that case, why not just pass the xml through a method that parses for the Number tag, then replaces the contents with astericks apart from the last four digits?

Comment: Ok. Thnks.  Do you have sample on this ?

Comment: Not to hand, no. However if you have any issues with implementing your own you know a good website to ask questions on  :)

Comment: Ok, Thnks I will try. This is not urgent task. But I have to do. Thnks for your timing.

Comment: Here I have provided answer based on the Kevin D suggestions. Here I just replaced the Credit card number with xxxxx fields when writing to the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        String reqXml                           = "" ;      

        String creditCardNumber                 = "1234567890128899" ;      

        reqXml = "<RentalPaymentPref>" +
        "<PaymentCard CardType=\"1\" CardCode=\"VI\" CardNumber=\""+creditCardNumber+"\" ExpireDate=\"0912\" SeriesCode=\"123\">" +
        "<CardHolderName>Ruchira kariyawasam</CardHolderName>" +
        "</PaymentCard>" + 
        "</RentalPaymentPref>" ;        

        StringBuffer reqXmlString = new StringBuffer(reqXml.toString());    

        short startIndex    = (short)(reqXml.indexOf("CardNumber")+12);


       if(null!=creditCardNumber && (!creditCardNumber.equals("")))
        {
            reqXmlString.replace(startIndex,(startIndex+12),"xxxxxxxxxxxx");            
        }    

        System.out.println("reqXmlString---->"+reqXmlString);


// Remaining file writing code goes here.
```

Here check whether card number is blank or empty. If we get the card number, then only mask the string content while writing to the file.

Output

```
<RentalPaymentPref>
<PaymentCard CardType="1" CardCode="VI" CardNumber="xxxxxxxxxxxx8899" ExpireDate="0912" SeriesCode="123">
<CardHolderName>Ruchira kariyawasam</CardHolderName>
</PaymentCard>
</RentalPaymentPref>
```